# ls command not giving true file size

Tags: nautilus, files

(newbie - just signed up) I am wondering why when I type the ls -l, ls -lh etc, why it gives the size of my Download file as 4 kilobytes when it is actually 20.7 gigabytes when I click properties on the GUI.  I have looked at previous questions but did not find an answer to this seeming anomoly.  Thanks.
The other thing is being a newbie I hope I can find my question post again if there is a reply - not at all certain about this but have ticked the email reply box at least.

Answer (score 1):

`~/Downloads` is a directory, not a file. It simply points to the list of files that directory contains (i.e., the files you downloaded). `ls` gives you the size of that pointer, which is usually 4k.

When you view that directory in a file explorer, the program assumes you want the total size of files within that directory. You can get this from the command line, too, of course - try `du -hs Downloads`.

See [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/186849/238080) post for more info.

Comment: Thanks Jamie - I have been looking for a readable tutorial for newbies for weeks and finally found one at http://wiki.lib.sun.ac.za/images/c/ca/TLCL-13.07.pdf .  Thought I would add this for anyone with the same problem.